# How does a redux thunk function operate? What happens when a redux thunk function gets called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux-thunk, dispatch

I am struggling to wrap my head around the syntax/ understanding how the thunk function flow...
 i.e. the following function:

```
function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(increment());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

I think I mostly am confused by the passing in `dispatch` as an argument part. What exactly happens when `incrementAsync` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal Redux action is a plain JS object, as illustrated in the tutorial: https://redux.js.org/basics/actions

What Thunk does is to extend Redux so that actions can also be a function. When `incrementAsync` is called, it returns a new function that takes an argument `dispatch`. That function is then called by Redux (via Thunk), passing in the `dispatch()` function from Redux as an argument, enabling you to dispatch more actions (a)synchronously.

This is all taking advantage of the fact that JS functions are first-class members of the language and can be assigned to a variable, and passed around.

Comment: Thank you! That makes it clearer a bit. So, just to confirm my understanding is correct, every time the `incrementAsync` function is called, Redux Thunk will invoke the function that's returned?

Comment: Yes, that's right! There may be some exceptions to the rule (Like if an error occurs somewhere) but that's generally true.

Comment: Thank you so much!